# How to add Button in a Canvas?

Tags: java, user-interface, video

I have a canvas and inside the canvas i have a webcam. On top of the video image, i want to place an "Button" and attach an event, so that i have control for full screen and minimize it.
But this method is giving error, how to fix it?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Overlay"); 
        frame.setBackground(Color.RED);

        // Canvas, to have a video and on top a button    
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(); 
        Button button = new Button(canvas); // ERROR
        button.setBounds(10,10, 100, 40);
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));     

        // Layout
        JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        content.add(canvas);
        content.add(new JButton("test"));  // for empty cell

        // Show
        frame.add(content);                        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.pack(); 
        frame.setVisible(true); 

        // Third party tools to capture the webcam, and plugin to our canvas
        final Video video = player.getElementByName("gl"); 
        XOverlay.wrap(video).setWindowID(canvas); 
    }
```

Comment: The error message is quite explanatory. This constructor does not exist. You have to create the button first and then add it to a container (btw canvas is no container). And you mix swing and awt components. Be very careful about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives error because there are no constructor in `Button` class that takes `canvas` as an argument.You can add your button to same JPanel where you are adding your canvas.

Comment: Adding into jPanel is seperating the button from Overlay. So the video is seperate and button is seperate. I have a full screen video running, and i need a button on top right corner.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas.add(button);
```

or

```
canvas.add(button, 55, 30);
```